# Run PyUnit tests in order

Tags: python, python-unittest

Is there any way I can execute the tests in the order in which they were written?

What happens in PyUnit is whenever I run tests it run in **alphabetical order**. This means even if I have written TestA after TestB, TestA will run before TestA. Which is creating problems for me.

```
import unittest

class SimpleTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def testB(self):
        print "Test B"

    def testA(self):
        print "Test A"
```

I want `testB` to execute before `testA`.

Comment: And btw, you should use search feature more extensively in the future, because the question has been asked numerous times at SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843171/unit-testing-with-dependencies-between-tests http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095319/unittest-tests-order

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for it using PyTest ordering plugin provided [here](http://pytest-ordering.readthedocs.org/en/develop/).

Try `py.test YourModuleName.py -vv` in CLI and the test will run in the order they have appeared in your module (first testB and then testA)

I did the same thing and works fine for me.

Note: You need to install PyTest package and import it.

Answer (score 0):

If these are unit tests then they should be completely isolated, so you should check for design flaws in those tests.

If you really need for some reason, to use a specific order, than you have three ways of achieving this in python:

1. Using unittest - change sorting method, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005695/changing-order-of-unit-tests-in-python).
2. Using Proboscis - use the following decorator @test(depends_on=[list of dependecies]), found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843171/unit-testing-with-dependencies-between-tests).
3. Using nose - nose executes its unit tests in the order in which they appear in the module file. More info [here](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/writing_tests.html).

Comment: Hi Guys, I gone through the Answers And this is what i got. 1. use unittest.TestLoader.sortTestMethodsUsing = lambda _, x, y: cmp(y, x) or 2. Give the name such a way it gets executed in order.  However I want don't want to change the name and I am not able to find any function for first solution though which i can execute the order in which it has been written. Any solution ???

Comment: @GaurangShah And why can't you use the other two solutions?

Answer (score -1):

PyUnit uses TestLoaded which collects all testcases in a suite and runs them in alphabetical order

For example Test A runs before TEST B

In case you want to run TEST B first we have to create function and add Test B and then Test A

```
def suite():
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTest(SimpleTestCase('test_B'))
    suite.addTest(SimpleTestCase('test_A'))
    return suite
```

Comment: Whenever you link to a blog post, library, or other external resource you're involved in, [you must clearly indicate this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).