# How test name impact variable persistence between tests in Unittest?

Tags: python, unit-testing

How do I persist changes made within the same object inheriting from TestCase in unitttest?
I've referred to [Persist variable changes between tests in unittest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21447740/persist-variable-changes-between-tests-in-unittest).
And the following codes works well.

```
from unittest import TestCase, main as unittest_main

    class TestSimpleFoo(TestCase):

        def setUp(self):
            pass

        def test_a(self):
            TestSimpleFoo.foo = 'can'

        def test_f(self):
            self.assertEqual(TestSimpleFoo.foo, 'can')

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        unittest_main()
```

However, If I change the test name "test_a" to "test_u", the code will be failed. 
Anyone can tell how could this happen?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. I ignored the case execution order

Answer (score 0):

As you already noticed, the execution order is important here.  But, in fact, the deeper problem is, that your tests are not independent from each other.  Ideally, each test behaves like a complete program of its own, starting from a defined clean starting state, and cleaning up after execution.