# Python's unittest setUp function internal working

Tags: python, python-unittest

```
import unittest

class TestString(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.subject_list = ["Maths","Physics","Chemistry"]

    def test_student_1(self):
        self.assertListEqual(self.subject_list,["Maths","Physics","Chemistry"])
        self.subject_list.remove("Maths")

    def test_student_2(self):
        self.assertListEqual(self.subject_list,["Physics","Chemistry"])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Output : one failure and one success.

Does the setUp() loads a copy of every variable defined in it for every test case ?? If yes, How can I use setUp() to access variables globally??

Comment: Just keep in mind that it's not a very good test - there is no guarantee that tests will be run in declaration order and then not even have to be run as suite (you can select subset of tests to run).

Comment: I don't know about the order of execution but it seems so that the setup method creates a local variable for every test case. So for the above example the order of execution doesn't matter. Yeah for global variables I have to check. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

setUp run each test method. if you want to run only once, use [setUpClass](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUpClass)

My English isn't good. so this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21447740/persist-variable-changes-between-tests-in-unittest) helps you

```
import unittest


class TestString(unittest.TestCase):
    subject_list = ["Maths", "Physics", "Chemistry"]

    def test_student_1(self):
        self.assertListEqual(self.subject_list, ["Maths", "Physics", "Chemistry"])
        self.subject_list.remove("Maths")

    def test_student_2(self):
        self.assertListEqual(self.subject_list, ["Physics", "Chemistry"])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: So do i need to declare that as kind of a static variable in python??? If yes how is that accessible using self??