# Python to write function that check dependencies on other functions

Tags: python, python-unittest

Would like to ask for some advice/ available libraries that can be use to check dependencies between functions.
Function test_isupper() will need to check if test_upper()function is successfully run. Else, not going to run test_isupper()

```
import unittest

class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_upper(self):
        self.assertEqual('foo'.upper(), 'FOO')

    def test_isupper(self):
        self.assertTrue('FOO'.isupper())
        self.assertFalse('Foo'.isupper())
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unit-testing with dependencies between tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843171/unit-testing-with-dependencies-between-tests)

Answer (score 0):

[repeated]

- See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843171/unit-testing-with-dependencies-between-tests)
- Pay close attention to the advice provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3843237/5329465)
- Note [TestNG](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependent-methods) is referenced