# Python Unitest Skip a Test if a particular previous test result is fail

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to skip a test if a previous test result is fail ,in the below code i want to skip test_2 if test_1 is fail

```
import unittest

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_1(self):
        assert False



    def test_2(self):
        check_test_result_test_1 = "" # how
        if check_test_result == "Fail":
            self.skipTest("skip as one is fail")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unit-testing with dependencies between tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843171/unit-testing-with-dependencies-between-tests)

Comment: @Daviid thanks for the revert but its not python UT related

Comment: Just FYI, I wanted to point to the answer not the question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57683262/6328256

Comment: @SashSinha thanks the plugin is for pytest is there anything similar for unit test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one test depends on another test's success to run at all, the test should be made a part of the same test instead. You can use the [`TestCase.subTest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.subTest) method to annotate the different phases of the test:

```
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_phases(self):
        with self.subTest('Phase 1'):
            self.assertTrue(False)
        with self.subTest('Phase 2'):
            self.assertTrue(True)
```

This produces a more descriptive error message like:

```
======================================================================

FAIL: test_phases (__main__.MyTest) [Phase 1]
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prog.py", line 6, in test_phases
AssertionError: False is not true

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/mSXl3O